# Storing XML into PHP Session Variable

Tags: php, xml

I read this is possible to do in ASP, but I need to know if I can do this in PHP.

I have to save in a database the data from 4 different forms. These forms are in separate PHP files and I can't store them one by one, I need to store them all at the same time.

Is there any possible way to store data from the first/second/etc form into xml as Session variable so at the end  I would be able to read them all, get all the data and store it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see why not.  Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Page 1

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['xml'] = '<xml><foo>bar</foo></xml>;
```

Page 2

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['xml'];
```

Ensure session_start() is called before the headers are sent